# Type 'CameraViewController' has no member 'handleTap'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller:

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.recordingSpinner.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CameraViewController.handleTap(_:)))
        self.recordingSpinner.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        if setupSession(){
            setupPreview()
            startSession()
        }
    }

    @objc func handleTap(gesture:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        startRecording()
        guard let animator = animator else {
            createAnimation()
            return
        }

        if animator.isRunning {
            animator.pauseAnimation()
        } else {
            animator.startAnimation()
        }
    }
}
```

XCode complains that it can't find handleTap in CameraViewController but I see it. What do I need to change?

Comment: Your function would have to be declared as `@objc func handleTap(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)` with the unnamed parameter to match the selector you're passing.

Comment: @dan you are correct that fixed it

Comment: Or change the `#selector` to `#selector(handleTap)` or `#selector(handleTap(gesture:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dan suggested, doing `@objc func handleTap(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)` instead of `@objc func handleTap(gesture:UIGestureRecognizer)` fixed it.

Also using         `let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)`
 works as well